# How do you resize a background image in css?

Tags: html, css

Down below is my code. I do not know how to resize the image as it is in one whole line of code. Do i create a new line of code and use a tag? I do not know what to do. Is there anything wrong?

```
#centerpicture {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url("Enderman_wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

only one eye of the sprite is showing but it should show as one whole face of the sprite.

Comment: Hello SKY PAMPOSA ANGELES you will need to use the background-size property in order to resize the background image.  The information you need is here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp if you would like to then position the background once you have resized it you will then need to use background-position that information is here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: A Google search would have provided you with all the answers :) But I explained it briefly in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following properties to size your background images:

```
background-size: cover; 
background-size: contain;
background-size: 30%; //using percentages
background-size: 100px 200px // using pixels
```

Play around with those properties and see what suits you best. Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for more information.

To position your background image, use the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) property.

**Code style:**

You can declare `background` properties on separate lines, or use the [shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

```
background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
```

In your case, you can use this:

```
background: url('Enderman_wallpaper.jpg') 0%/30% no-repeat;
```

Comment: yes. i know that, but how do i add "background-size: 30%;" to my current code,"background: url("Enderman_wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat;" in just one line?